# Redoing Bar tape and outer cables

Tags: parts

I recently bought a road bike that needed some work, I fitted new inner and outer brake and gear cables for the first time as well as replacing the bar tape, Now around 6 months later I have realised the outer gear housing is way to long, near the wheel but not touching, Is it possible to re-do it without replacing it?
Same for the bar tape, I did it ok but first time and now it is moving and exposing the bars.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to shorten existing cables and cable housings. This can be difficult if you're only shortening it by a small amount, and you've cut short the tail of the cable beyond the fixing bolt. Otherwise it's no different than using new cable and housing.

I've never had good luck re-wrapping bar tape myself.

Comment: Some bar tape is completely impossible to rewrap, if it has a self adhesive strip that's stronger than the tape. Better bar tape relies on a grippy inner surface and good wrapping, and can be rewrapped to some extent

Answer (score 3):

Bartape can generally be reused, unless it is physically deteriorated with tears or gouges.  Even then it can sometimes be applied "opposite-lay" so what was exposed originally ends up covered by the following wrap.  Used bartape makes an acceptable inner wrap if you intend on double-wrapping.  Foam bartape tends to break down quickly, whereas leather-like tapes will last for many years and multiple rewraps.

Tips  for applying bartape is to use low-medium constant tension, and if there's an adhesive backer to peel off the covering in some places but not others.   Have your termination tape pre-cut and ready to hand.  Also know what you intend to do at the hoods/brake levers.  Everyone has their own "right" way to do it.

Remember since the bartape is already coming loose and annoying you, a rewrap won't make it any worse - the worst case is you need to buy new bartape anyway.

---

You can absolutely shorten brake and gear outers.  Do remember to withdraw the inner cable before cutting - they have to be longer.  This can lead to issues re-inserting, if the end is somewhat bent and binds in the outer.

The right tools help a lot.  You want a cable cutter, not pliers or a hacksaw.  A dremel+cutoff wheel makes a fair cut too, but you will need a file and a pokey thing to open the liner.  If your bike uses ferrules, you'll want new ones to cap the end of the outer.

---

Upshot - give it a go, you might surprise yourself.  I suggest doing one brake at a time, not both together.  Just allow yourself time, don't rush, and if there are problems stop and think it through, search the site for answers, or try [chat]   You can do this.

Comment: the chat link should have parsed to [chat]

Answer (score 1):

There are excellent instruction videos on YouTube (from Parktool, GCN or others) on how to wrap bar-tape and on how to perfect brake and gear cabling. Especially for cabling, buying a good cable & housing cutter (~20£/$/€) is well invested money and saves a lot of frustration and swearing.

Some bartape comes off easier if you want to re-use it by applying slight heat from a hairdryer. Start at low heat if it has several levels. If the tape has been slipping it will probably come off quite easily. Some tape is very sticky and will disintegrate when you're trying to unwind it. It's a good idea to have a new one ready.

Answer (score 0):

> Now around 6 months later I have realised the outer gear housing is way to long, near the wheel but not touching, Is it possible to re-do it without replacing it?

You can always shorten the housing, but never make it longer.

However, you need to remove the end cap from the inner cable (usually requires cutting the cable to become a bit shorter) and also remove and re-attach the cable and its end cap. This will make the cable a bit shorter so if it's already too short you may need to have a new cable. Since you are planning of shortening the housing, I believe you can use a slightly shorter inner cable.

Do note that many brakes damage the housing where you clamp it. Thus brake inner cable reuse might not be a good idea. This problem is less severe on shifting cables because derailleurs aren't safety critical so they don't have the stupid retention feature that damages the cable once clamped.

> Same for the bar tape, I did it ok but first time and now it is moving and exposing the bars.

If the bar tape is moving, not from the ends, but rather from the middle, there are two causes of this:

- Improper technique
- Poor quality bar tape

When wrapping the handlebars, the proper technique is to always maintain high constant tension. Don't ever release the tension! If you have a mobile phone nearby, put it to silent mode when wrapping the bars. Also ensure you have access to all tools you may need, such as scissors, the end tape, and also a hot soldering iron used to heat the end tape very slightly to weld it (because by pure adhesion the end tape won't stay there) -- be careful with the soldering iron though, because a fraction of a second too much heating will make holes in the end tape.

The other possible cause may be using an off-brand bar tape that is not good enough for cycling applications. The proper attributes of a bar tape needed to maintain it long-term are:

- High friction on both sides, including the side towards the handlebars, so that it won't slide on the bars and that your hands won't slide on the tape
- Good quality adhesive on the side that goes towards the bars.
- Springiness. If you tension a piece of ordinary tape (not bar tape), you note it doesn't spring much. You can apply very great forces and it only stretches very little. Then eventually it breaks. So it's not springy. A bar tape needs to be springy. It needs to elongate a lot when you apply force, and return to its original length when you stop applying force. This property is important because otherwise slight changes in the bar tape length (bar tape sliding) can completely eliminate the tension after being applied on the handlebar. This elimination of the tension progresses rapidly, leading to bar tape that won't stay where it should stay, exposing parts of the bars. A springy bar tape on the other hand would, if being moved slightly in a way that reduces its length by a little, maintain most of its tension so that it won't continue exposing more and more of the bars.

And oh, don't reuse the old bar tape. If there's 50% chance of being applied using an improper technique and 50% change of being poor quality bar tape, I'd say there's a fair chance a different type of bar tape might work better.